# Google AdSense throwing error - Only one 'enable page level ads allowed per page'

Tags: javascript, wordpress, typeerror, ads, adsense

I built a WordPress site (Newspaper template) and wanted to add Google AdSense. After approval I added the code, but it gives me the error listed below:

> Uncaught 
>   M {message: "adsbygoogle.push() error: Only one 'enable_page_level_ads' allowed per page.", name: "TagError", pbr: true, stack: "TagError: adsbygoogle.push() error: Only one 'enab…syndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js:1:21800)"}
>   message: "adsbygoogle.push() error: Only one 'enable_page_level_ads' allowed per page."

I have no idea what to do. Does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 3):

hmm.. maybe script code that Google Adsense had provided was written down two or more on your website.

```
    <script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
google_ad_client: "your client id",
enable_page_level_ads: true
  });
</script>
```

check this script if it was duplicated.
If you clear the duplicate, the error will disappear.

Have a nice day :D

Answer (score 1):

Check your website's page source for multiple AdSense code. Use Ctrl+U (or view-source:website.com), Ctrl+F and search for *pub-*.

If you are using WordPress you might have two code

1. Inserted via Google Sitekit plugin

```
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
google_ad_client: "ca-pub-****************",
enable_page_level_ads: true,
tag_partner: "site_kit"
});
</script>
```

2. Direct insertion

`<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-****************" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>`

Removing one of these code to resolve this issue.

Comment: note that only the old method is allowed to modify the default parameters, that is, option 2 (Direct insertion) is not allowed